# Make a field to auto increment when I press CONFIRM SALE

Tags: python, xml, odoo-9

[image]

I have made the field 'internal reference' in customers to be auto increment as you can see on the picture (001, 002, 003....).
That happens every time I create a new customer.

Now my problem is that I want the same (internal reference to be auto increment) but not when I create a customer but when I click CONFIRM SALE button.

Can someone help me with the Python code and .xml file how can I do that?

It should be something like this but still is the thing I search:

```
@api.onchange('state', 'partner_id')
def _onchange_partner(self): 
    if self.partner_id: contact_id = self.partner_id.address_get().get('contact', False)
        if contact_id: contact = self.env['res.partner'].browse(contact_id) self.name = self.name or contact.name –
```

Comment: it should be something like this but still is the thing i search



@api.onchange('state', 'partner_id')

    def _onchange_partner(self):
        if self.partner_id:
            contact_id = self.partner_id.address_get().get('contact', False)
            if contact_id:
                contact = self.env['res.partner'].browse(contact_id)
                self.name = self.name or contact.name

Answer (score 0):

You want something to trigger when the "Confirm Sale" Button is pressed?

Maybe look at overwriting "def action_confirm(self)" in the sale.order model (untested).

Comment: Yes Palza. When i press confirm sale button it should increase the Internal Reference field ('ref') by one. 
For example: I create new sale order, and then i create a new customer for that sale order and then i save it. After that i press the confirm sale button and the Internal Reference field should auto increment by one. If i make sale order for existing customer then it should do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Just a more detailed example of Palza's answer above (which is correct). Override the action_confirm() method from sale.sale model. I think some variation of this should do the trick.

```
class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = "sale.order"

    @api.multi
    def action_confirm(self):
        import logging
        _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        _logger.info("OVERRIDING action_confirm()")
        _logger.info("CURRENT INT REF: " + str(self.internal_reference))  
        self.write({'internal_reference':self.internal_reference+1})
        _logger.info("NEW INT REF: " + str(self.internal_reference))
        return super(SaleOrder, self).action_confirm()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This not works. When i create a new sale order add a new customer for that order and after saving i click CONFIRM SALE the 'ref' field stays empty.
In my case this field should increase by one every time i click confirm sale.
Of course if i make an order for existing customer it will be the same Internal reference.

Comment: Should i overwrite completely the action_confirm()?

Comment: Can you please help me somehow?

Comment: So you have overridden the SaleOrder.action_confirm() function. Place some logging in it. I will edit above to demonstrate. In your logs if you are successfully running your function you will see the logging.

Comment: I paste your code above in my .py file. I don't have any errors but still when i press confirm sale button my internal reference field is empty, it does not increase by 1.

Comment: I tried with this before but still don't work 

@api.onchange('state')
@api.onchange('partner_id')
    def _onchange_partner(self):
        if self.partner_id:
            contact_id = self.partner_id.address_get().get('contact', False)
            if contact_id:
                contact = self.env['res.partner'].browse(contact_id)
                self.name = self.name or contact.name

Comment: You cant update a database record in onchange functions. @api.onchange will not throw error but simply will not write into the database.

Comment: Maybe i need to put this code inside the action_confirm code:

@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    vals['ref'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].get('res.debt')
    return super(Partner, self).create(vals)                        This is the code for auto increment the field ref

Comment: You can override the function of just edit the original function depending on your situation. Overriding the function is safer. Im not sure about your create function. This logic is tied to the button click so to me it makes sense to have it in that function.

Comment: I think a need a code that i can use it.
So please phillipstack try to re-edit the code above if you know how exactly to do this?
Thanks